# android studio rebuild error : Unable to find Gradle tasks to build why?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[image]i have an android studio project with manifest file, the problem is when i sync the gradle it gives the error below

```
Gradle sync failed: Cannot get property 'sync' on null object
```

also this is the exception

```
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'projectname'.
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:49)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor$1.run(BuildScriptProcessor.java:45)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:212)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:193)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:107)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:189)
at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:238)
```

Comment: Can you provide your *.gradle files?

Comment: please check my post I added a new image @Androiderson

Comment: Is this happening suddenly? If so can you invalidate cache/restart your IDE?

Comment: not suddenly, the project is new and i am trying to import or open it but doesn't work

Comment: You need to supply your configuration files content (build.gradle, settings.gradle, etc) and anything related to your build configuration.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have tried to rename and remove the line with `include ':app'` from my `settings.gradle` or `settings.gradle.kts` file, Sync Project  with Gradle files and revert the removed line and sync again. But it does not work for me.

What works for me is;

1. delete folders [`build`, `.idea`, `.gradle`]
2. resync or Invalidate Caches / Restart
3. and do the same steps by removing `include ':app'`, etc. (optional step, if does not work)

Note: This works for me for my project that is configured with `.kts` files and do it with precautions.

Comment: Thanks for now it has corrupted my entire project.

Comment: Just step 1 and 2 are enough

Comment: Unclear instructions. My computer exploded.

Comment: @Viroth's answer was all that I needed, try that first before deleting files

Answer (score 12):

- Clean project
- Invalidate cache
- Synce gradle project again. It will be fixed!

Comment: it wasn`t, in my case I had to upgrade Android Studio. (Help -> Check for updates). Now I have electric eel version. Much better performance, better build times. I updated everything, gradle plugin, libraries, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I have commented

```
include ':app'
```

and it allowed me to build my project

Comment: After clearing the cache, delete the build folder, and restart AS. I commented out this line and tried to sync, and it fails, then I uncommented it, synced, and it worked.

Comment: @Quimbo There is no `:app` in my `settings.gradle` but I am having the same error after upgrading from Android Studio `2021.3.1` to `2022.1.1`. Attempting to `Sync Project with Gradle Files` results in Sync error. I then `Invalidate Caches` (all of them) and restarted AS, and also deleted all `build` folders, but I am still getting Sync failed. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: @WebViewer Try to add the settings.gradle to your root project and add this to the file.

`include ':app'
rootProject.name = "root-project-folder-name"`

Comment: Thank you @Quimbo. I lucked out yesterday and managed to find the solution on my own. It wasn't trivial at all. I documented the process, as it is possible that others will encounter this, too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75221722/2597758

Comment: For me my project was missing include ':app' and when i added it , it worked and built successfully. Because of this i checkd it

Answer (score 2):

delete folders build,.idea,.gradle and resync or Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but you needed to Update and Clean build everything first to proceed.

PS: I was using Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was displaying below error.

[image]

It successfully build and run after applying multiple solution.

1. **gradle-wrapper.properties**:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip`

2. **build.gradle(project-level)**:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

3. Replace below in **build.gradle(app-level)**:

- compile -> implementation
- testCompile -> testImplementation
- etc...

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything above to no avail. My problem was after all Case Sensitivity related

```
rootProject.name = "Konka" should be rootProject.name = "konka"
```

in `settings.gradle.kts`

Answer (score -2):

These steps helped me :

1. delete folders [build, .idea, .gradle]
2. resync or Invalidate Caches / Restart

- after that restore deleted folders from Recycle Bin back cause project became corrupted. After that project works and can be build

Answer (score -3):

this works for me
delete folders [build, .idea, .gradle]
resync or Invalidate Caches / Restart
and do the same steps by removing include ':app', etc.