# Android app error while building in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Please guide me I'm beginner. I'm working on Android app which I've developed in java it was working fine but from last a few days it's giving error when i try to build it.

unable to find gradle tasks to build [;]. Build mode: ASSEMBLE Test: none

[here is the picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soP9L.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked this? I think something went wrong while you updated to gradle 8.x

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69168533/android-studio-rebuild-error-unable-to-find-gradle-tasks-to-build-why

Answer (score 0):

If you use a proxy I suggest You look at this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239471023).

Pay attention to it :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).